# Print Webpage is not showing full pages

Tags: html, printing, scroll

I created a website with low-code application, when I'm trying to print the page by right click its not show or print the entire website, it only show 1 page whatever section we scrolled and it showing scroll bar inside the page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7X4gL.jpg) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hehpv.jpg)

Expecting solution by CSS/HTML.

Comment: Please take the [tour]. See also [ask] and in your Question add a [mre]